# ggplot2 Annotating facets error with dates

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to add labels to a `facet_grid` plot. I would like to achieve the following result:

[image]

The below is reproducible code to create the data frame and plot. Data frame `annotation_text` is storing the facet variable vs label value mapping:

```
myDF <- data.frame(
  some_data = c(3.32, 3.34, 3.41, 3.45, 3.42, 3.44, 3.51, 3.55, 3.32, 3.34, 3.41, 3.45, 3.36, 3.41, 3.50, 3.54, 3.32, 3.34, 3.41, 3.45, 3.32, 3.44, 3.51, 3.42),
  date = as.Date(rep(c('2018-01-01', '2018-02-01', '2018-03-01', '2018-04-01'), 6)),
  segment = rep(c('segment1', 'segment2', 'segment3'), each = 4, n = 2),
  series = rep(c('series1', 'series2'), each = 12))

annotation_text <- data.frame(
  segment = c('segment1', 'segment2', 'segment3'), 
  label = c('label1', 'label2', 'label3'))

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(myDF, aes(x = date, y = some_data, fill = series)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(size = 2, shape = 21) +
  facet_grid(. ~ segment) +
  ylim(0, 5)
```

I am attempting to add the labels using the below

```
p + geom_text(
  data = annotation_text, mapping = aes(x = -Inf, y = -Inf, label = label, fill = NULL, inherit.aes = FALSE, parse = FALSE), hjust = -0.3, vjust = -1)
```

But this returns the following error:

> Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only

Any help on this error appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The x scale is the underlying numeric values of the dates (in units of days elapsed since January 1, 1970) and the x values in the annotation need to be of Date class. The error has something to do with ggplot looking for and not finding a `date` column in `annotation_text` with which to position the labels, or some other column with values of Date class and specified as the x aesthetic in `geom_text()`.

One option would be to provide the date values with the `annotation_text` data frame, so that ggplot knows where to position the labels. This can be done by filtering `myDF` to the earliest `date` for each `segment` (assuming you want the labels placed at that x location) and joining it to `annotation_text`. We do that on the fly within `geom_text()` below.

In the code below `.` is a "pronoun" through which we access the `myDF` data frame that was supplied in the original `ggplot()` call. `hjust=0` left justifies the labels and `y=0.1` hard-codes the y position.

```
library(tidyverse) # To make both ggplot2 and the dplyr pipe available

p + geom_text(data = . %>% 
                arrange(date) %>% 
                group_by(segment) %>% 
                slice(1) %>% 
                left_join(annotation_text), 
              aes(label = label), y=0.1, hjust=0)
```

[image]

Some other options and examples that will hopefully clarify what's going wrong or right:

Hard-code the x position to be the minimum date in `myDF`. Also need to add the `series` column to `annotation_text` or ggplot throws an error. Note that this works here because the x position of the labels is the same in each facet. If we wanted the labels in a different x position in each facet, then we would need to provide the desired date location in each panel. The previous method does that through grouping by `segment` and then selecting the lowest date in each level of `segment`:

```
p + geom_text(data = annotation_text %>% mutate(series=NA), 
              aes(label = label), y=0.1, x=min(myDF$date), hjust=0)
```

Same as above, but `inherit.aes=FALSE` avoids need to add `series` column to `annotation_text`:

```
p + geom_text(data = annotation_text, 
              aes(label = label), y=0.1, x=min(myDF$date), hjust=0, inherit.aes=FALSE)
```

Add minimum date to `annotation_text` (with same column name `date`), so that ggplot knows where the labels go:

```
p + geom_text(data = annotation_text %>% 
                mutate(series=NA, 
                       date=min(myDF$date)), 
              aes(label = label), y=0.1, hjust=0)
```

The next one fails because we've converted `date` to numeric, so it's the wrong class:

```
p + geom_text(data = annotation_text %>% 
                mutate(series=NA, 
                       date=as.numeric(min(myDF$date))), 
              aes(label = label), y=0.1, hjust=0)
```

Provide the date column in `annotation_text`, but with a new name (`new.date`) that we now need to supply inside aes, so that ggplot knows where to get the x values from:

```
p + geom_text(data = annotation_text %>% 
                mutate(series=NA, 
                       new.date=min(myDF$date)), 
              aes(x=new.date, label = label), y=0.1, hjust=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

While I appreciate [<sup>eipi10's elaborated answer</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55125198/ggplot2-annotating-facets-error-with-dates/55126173#55126173), here's another option using `annotate`.

```
p + 
   annotate("text", label = annotation_text$label, size = 4, 
            x = min(myDF$date), 
            y = 0 ,
            hjust = -0.3, vjust = -1)
```

you can set `y` to the following to avoid hard-coding its value.

`y = min(ggplot_build(p)$layout$coord$labels(ggplot_build(p)$layout$panel_params)[[1]]$y.major_source)`

[image]